# I am getting "use of undeclared Identifier 'LOGD'" error in Tizen Native Project

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

When I am adding app-assist-efl library with my project, it shows error:
**use of undeclared Identifier 'LOGD'** in app-assist-library.

Have anyone seen this error in Tizen Native Proejct?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing macro definition of "LOGD".
Add definition like for example in your code :

```
// define it within your source code 
#define LOGD(x,y,z) dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG,x,y,z)

.........
.........
// Usage like internally
int h=9;
LOGD("theTag", "Create Base gui Called: %d",h);
```

For more information about logging see below link:
https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.3.1/org.tizen.guides/html/native/system/dlog_n.htm

and also

https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/tutorial_log_page.html

Hope it will help.